# JUST SHARE - MySQL DataSet into Json Format using delphi SuperObject

Tags: json, delphi, superobject

Just share my experience using [Json using Delphi SuperObject](http://code.google.com/p/superobject)

The idea is how to convert my query result into json format easily.

I use string to represent all data format (including BLOB, DATE, DATETIME). In future the json file can be imported into database easily.

I do not write the code from scratch, i just made a little modification suited into my own need

Here is the code :

```
function TTableJSon.CreateJsonValueByFieldMySql(Json: ISuperObject;
  Field: TField): Boolean;
var
  JsonTyp, FieldTyp : string;
  tmpStr : string;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Field Is TDateField then begin
      Json.O[Field.FieldName] := SO('"'+FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',Field.AsDateTime)+'"')
  end else if Field Is TDateTimeField then begin
      Json.O[Field.FieldName] := SO('"'+FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss',Field.AsDateTime)+'"')
  end else if Field is TMemoField then begin
      Json.S[Field.FieldName] := EncodeString(Field.AsString)
  end else if Field is TBlobField then begin
      Json.S[Field.FieldName] := EncodeString(Field.AsString)
  end else if Field is TFloatField then begin
      Json.O[Field.FieldName] := SO(ReplaceStr(Field.AsString,',','.'))
  end else begin
        Json.O[Field.FieldName] := SO(Field.Value);
  end;
  Result := True;
end;


function TTableJSon.JSonFromDataSet(DataSet: TDataSet): string;
  procedure GetFieldTypeInfo(Field:TField;var Fieldtyp,JsonTyp:string);
  begin
      Fieldtyp := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TFieldType),ord(Field.DataType));
      Delete(Fieldtyp,1,2);
      if Field is TStringField then
        JsonTyp := 'string'
      else if Field is TDateTimeField then
        JsonTyp := 'integer'
      else if Field is TMemoField then
        JsonTyp := 'memo'
      else if Field is TBlobField then
        JsonTyp := 'blob'
      else if (Field is TIntegerField) or (Field is TLargeintField) then
        JsonTyp := 'integer'
      else if Field is TCurrencyField then
        JsonTyp := 'currency'
      else if Field is TNumericField then
        JsonTyp := 'double'
      else if Field is TBooleanField then
        JsonTyp := 'boolean'
      else
        JsonTyp := 'variant';
  end;

var
  sj,aj,sj2:ISuperObject;
  i:Integer;
  Fieldtyp,JsonTyp:string;
  List:TStringList;
begin
  sj := SO();
  aj := SA([]);
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
      List.Sorted := True;

      for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
      begin
        sj2 := SO();
        GetFieldTypeInfo(DataSet.Fields[i],Fieldtyp,JsonTyp);

        sj2.S[cstFieldName] := DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName;
        sj2.S[cstFieldType] := Fieldtyp;
        sj2.S[cstJsonType] := JsonTyp;
        sj2.I[cstFieldSize] := DataSet.Fields[i].Size;
        sj2.B[cstRequired] := DataSet.Fields[i].Required;
        sj2.I[cstFieldIndex] := DataSet.Fields[i].Index;
        aj.AsArray.Add(sj2);
        List.Add(DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName+'='+JsonTyp);
      end;
      sj.O['Cols'] := aj;
      DataSet.DisableControls;

      DataSet.First;
      aj := SA([]);
      while not DataSet.Eof do
      begin
        sj2 := SO();
        for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
        begin
          if VarIsNull(DataSet.Fields[i].Value) then
            sj2.O[DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName] := SO(Null)
          else begin
            CreateJsonValueByFieldMySql(sj2,DataSet.Fields[i]);
          end;
        end;
        aj.AsArray.Add(sj2);
        DataSet.Next;
      end;
      sj.O['Data'] := aj;

      Result := sj.AsString;
  finally
      List.Free;
      DataSet.EnableControls;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: I believe the question should be closed. I don't agree with -1 because yuda just shared some knowledge.

Comment: Hmm.. okay.. just close the issue.. i do not mind..

Comment: I too believe the question should be closed but please don't get upset by it, or worse, turn your back on SO. If you give us a chance, you will find a lot of valuable help here and can offer valuable help yourself to those who need it *(fwiw, the downvotes are completely undeserved imo)*.

Comment: This could easily be converted to a QA "shared" style . OP just needed to ask "how to convert my query result into json format?" describe the problem, and answer his own question. I have seen a lot of questions asked this way here on SO. and I think it's great :) Here is a [good example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446979/why-do-i-get-access-violations-when-a-controls-class-name-is-very-very-long) by @Cosmin Prund ;)

Comment: Thx, but where is "EncodeString(Field.AsString)" realisation?

Comment: There is no need to build similar to [TableToJSON](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSONCommon.TDBXJSONTools.TableToJSON) function if there is one. There are also useful library Data.DBXJSON that defines classes that implement dbExpress JSON support for dbExpress callbacks, JSON arrays, byte readers, numbers, objects, pairs, strings and values.